# In saptha vyasanalu, "speaking rudely" is also there or not

Tags: scripture, vedas, mahabharata, puranas, bhagavad-gita

In saptha vyasanalu, is speaking rudely is also there?
That means man is not by nature rude, only addicted to that character.
Please  any body explain.

Comment: Hello. Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange. This (sapta vyasana) seems to be a Jain concept or a subhashita. Are you sure it is related to Hinduism? Is your question about speaking rudely allowed and a sin or it is included in seven sorrows?

Comment: No,my question is about seven  addictions I.e, alcohol, playing cards, etc. In that speaking rudely also there or not.